# Exclude a WooCommerce product category from a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I've got the following args defined as a part of my query:

```
$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
        'author'                => $artist,
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'meta_query'            => array(
            array(
                'key'           => '_visibility',
                'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                'compare'       => 'IN'
        )
    )
) );
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I need to exclude a category called Magazines (slug "magazines") or ID 351 from the query.

I've been trying to include `'category__not_in' => array('magazines')`, so it looks like this:

```
$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'author'                => $artist,
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'category__not_in'      => array('magazines'),
            'meta_query'            => array(
                array(
                    'key'           => '_visibility',
                    'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                    'compare'       => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ) );
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But that just doesn't seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: category__not_in takes ARRAY as argument, make it array('magazines') an d check..!!

Comment: Hi there, updated my code, but still not working for me ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Product categories are a custom taxonomy `product_cat`.

So you need to do it in a simple `tax_query` this way:

```
$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', 
    array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
        'author'                => $artist,
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'meta_query'            => array(
             array(
                'key'           => '_visibility',
                'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                'compare'       => 'IN'
            ),
        ),
        'tax_query'            => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug', // Or 'name' or 'term_id'
                'terms'    => array('magazines'),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN', // Excluded
            )
        )
    ) 
);

$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: @JoeBloggs I have maid a mistake… I didn't pay attention but it has to be a `tax_query` for product category instead a `meta_query` … I have updated and complete… try it again

Comment: now you nailed it. Now it works great. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `category__not_in` value as an array like this

`$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 'magazines' ) ) );`

For details check this

[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

So please update your code into this

```
$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'author'                => $artist,
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'category__not_in'      => array('magazines')
            'meta_query'            => array(
                array(
                    'key'           => '_visibility',
                    'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                    'compare'       => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ) );
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Let me know whether its working or not for you.

Comment: Hi there, many thanks, but nope, not working form me, the category is still showing ..

Comment: Please try with category id and can you try to comment out the meta query section. Then check, whether its working or not?

Comment: So I tried the ID and also commented out the meta query section and tried again with slug or ID, but none of this seems to be working. Category is still showing.

Comment: Then please check whether the filter is actually working or not or somehow it is being override with something.