# Exclude products from a certain category, with Woocommerce and Elementor Anywhere

Tags: woocommerce, elementor

I am using Elementor Anywhere to create a specific display for my WooCommerce products.

I have a filter and for the filter works I need to use Post blocks Adv.

There I ask to display current archive.

I have the possibility to put a query filter, but I can't exclude products from a certain category.

I have this, but it doesn't work with current archives.

```
function filtrer_produit_sans_crea( $query_args ) {
    $query_args['meta_query']  = array(
        array(
            'key'   => '_stock_status',
            'value' => 'instock',
        ),
    );

    $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'coin-des-creatrices',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    );

    return $query_args;
}

add_filter( 'filtre_zero_dechet', 'filtrer_produit_sans_crea' );
```

Has anyone ever tried something like this?
Or do you have a clue?

Comment: Do you want to exclude the products only for the Elementor block or all over your page? If you want to exclude categories only for the Elementor block, I'm not sure if this can be done with a hook, since Elementor is not made for big customization outside of the builder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
If it's possible on all the pages it's perfect. 
There are products in this category that I could display differently on another page.

Comment: Sure. In this case, you should check this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630487/exclude-a-woocommerce-product-category-from-a-wp-query Excluding products from a specific category from a being displayed is one of the most mainly asked question. If it helps you, please close the question to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm not writing it correctly in my functions.php file. 
Should I put this code in an add_filter function?

Comment: Have you checked the other question? It shows you how to exclude a certain category.

Comment: Yes thank you very much I have looked and tested with my settings. Maybe it's Elementor Anywhere the problem. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a solution:

```
function mystore_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'coin-des-creatrices' ), // modifier la catégorie
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'mystore_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

But it does on the whole site.

If anyone has a clue how to do it only on a specific page...

Naively I wanted to add this:

```
function mystore_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
if ( is_page(  54 ) ) {
    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'coin-des-creatrices' ), // modifier la catégorie
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'mystore_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

But it's doesn't work ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I found another track.

```
function mystore_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'coin-des-creatrices' ), // modifier la catégorie
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );


}



add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_my_action');

function remove_my_action($post) {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if (160029  == $post_id) {
         echo "PAGE OK";
         add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mystore_pre_get_posts_query');
    }else{
        
        remove_action('pre_get_posts', 'mystore_pre_get_posts_query');
         
        
    }
}
```

My "page ok" displays well but the function does not launch.

If it is outside this function, the line  `add_action('pre_get_posts', 'mystore_pre_get_posts_query');`

does what I want it to do.

Is it `add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_my_action');` that is not the right one?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).